# Pass Dynamic Table Row Data to Modal Dialog via Delete Button

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-modal, ejs

**Context**
I have a `GET` route that loads a .ejs file which adds rows of data to a table based on the length of the passed variable `accounts`. Here `accounts` is an array of dictionaries with the keys `_id, type, nickname, rewards, balance, customer_id`.

```
    <% if (accounts.length > 0) { %>
      <% accounts.forEach(account => { %>
        <tr class="blue-grey lighten-3 account-row">
          <th scope="row" class="account-id"><%= account._id %></th>
          <td><%= account.type %></td>
          <td><%= account.nickname %></td>
          <td><%= account.rewards %></td>
          <td>$<%= account.balance %></td>
          <td><%= account.customer_id %></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table-remove">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 remove" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeAccountModal">
                Remove
              </button>
            </span>
          </td>
          <div class="modal fade" id="removeAccountModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="removeAccountModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="removeAccountModalLabel">You are about to remove this account</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  CAUTION!!!
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  Removing this account will delete all the data associated with it. You must visit a local branch to retrieve any monies left residing in the account.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn grey darken-1" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <form id="remove-form" action="/" method="POST">
                    <button id="removeAccount" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Remove Account</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tr>
      <% }) %>
```

**Issue**
There is a delete button on each row of data that opens a Bootstrap modal confirming that the user wants to indeed delete that row's data. Upon a submit in the modal, this will initiate a `DELETE` request in the form of a `form` element.

I want to pass the selected row's associated `account._id` variable so that I can modify the `form`'s `action` attribute to `/<%= account._id %>/?_METHOD=DELETE`.

*I am having trouble accessing the modal's parent window DOM elements.*

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("loaded and ready to go!"); // works as expected
  var $remove = $(".remove"); // works as expected
  console.log($remove.length); // works as expected
  $(".remove").click(() => {
   console.log("I'm in the modal!") // works as expected
   var $parent = $(this).parent().closest("tr"); // find row
   console.log($parent); // w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(0)]
   var $account_id = $parent.find("th"); // find account id
   console.log($account_id); // w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(0)]
   console.log($account_id.text()); // returns blank type string
   $("#remove-form").prop("action", "/" + $account_id + "?
    _method=DELETE"); // change action attribute to account id value
   })
 });
</script>
```

**Methods tried:**

```
console.log(window.parent.$(this).closest("tr"));       
// returns w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

Comment: why don't you place the id  in action like this  `action="/<%= account._id %>/`

Comment: It will take the first row’s data no matter which delete button row you select. I need a way to pass the specific row’s account id value to the action attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @dimitris tseggenes for pointing me in the right direction.
The unique `id`s for each modal div was imperative here. It turns out the `id` attribute value must not solely consist of numbers.

I refactored the `id` and `target-data` attributes to look like the following, respectively:

`id="account<%= account._id %>id"`
`data-target=#account"<%= account._id %>id"`

I have learned the following from the responses in this post:

1. Don't forget to make modal divs unique if you will have multiple modals, i.e. in a table and to alter the action element respectively using the data-target attribute
2. id attributes must not solely contain numbers

Answer (score 0):

you have placed the modal inside the `forEach` loop. So you dont have only one modal, instead you have one for each row. The problem here is that you assigned the same id `removeAccountModal` for all of them. Try to assign a unique id for each modal, for example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<%= account._id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="removeAccountModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

and on each delete button replace data-target with

```
data-target="#<%= account._id %>"
```

So you have unique modals and now you can place `<%= account._id %>` directly in action attribute

Comment: I've made the suggested edits and received this error:  

    `util.js:85 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 
    '#5c7814646759394351bee3f8' is not a valid selector.`

The error is referring to the remove button that initiates the modal:  
    `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 remove" 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= account._id %>">Remove</button>`